# I get null from a SQL query in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a problem trying to get data from a specific meta_value in WordPress, that is, when I do a "`WHERE AND (PM.meta_key= 'webm' and PM.meta_value= 'Chaturbate')`" in the sql query. When I don't use where and get all the data it usually looks like this:

[image]

```
SELECT P.ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PM.meta_key = 'nombrem' THEN PM.meta_value END) AS nombrem,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PM.meta_key = 'generom' THEN PM.meta_value END) AS generom,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PM.meta_key = 'tiempom' THEN PM.meta_value END) AS tiempom,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PM.meta_key = 'urlm'    THEN PM.meta_value END) AS urlm,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PM.meta_key = 'imagenm' THEN PM.meta_value END) AS imagenm
FROM 
    K1nG_posts AS P
    LEFT JOIN K1nG_postmeta AS PM ON P.ID = PM.post_id 
WHERE 
    P.post_type = 'post' 
    AND (P.post_status = 'publish' OR P.post_status = 'private')
GROUP BY P.ID, P.post_date
```

But when I use the "`WHERE AND (PM.meta_key= 'webm' and PM.meta_value= 'Chaturbate')`" in a meta_value of a respective meta_key called "webm", I get the matching records but without the "select" information, that is, null, as can be seen in the image:
[image]

```
SELECT P.ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PM.meta_key = 'nombrem' THEN PM.meta_value END) AS nombrem,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PM.meta_key = 'generom' THEN PM.meta_value END) AS generom,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PM.meta_key = 'tiempom' THEN PM.meta_value END) AS tiempom,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PM.meta_key = 'urlm'    THEN PM.meta_value END) AS urlm,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PM.meta_key = 'imagenm' THEN PM.meta_value END) AS imagenm
FROM 
    K1nG_posts AS P
    LEFT JOIN K1nG_postmeta AS PM ON P.ID = PM.post_id 
WHERE 
    P.post_type = 'post' 
    AND (P.post_status = 'publish' OR P.post_status = 'private')
    AND (PM.meta_key= 'webm' and PM.meta_value= 'Chaturbate')
GROUP BY P.ID, P.post_date
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score -1):

try to use this code

```
 WHERE 
   P.post_type = 'post' 
   AND P.post_status = 'publish' OR P.post_type = 'post' AND P.post_status = 'private'
```

this basically takes

```
P.post_type = 'post' AND P.post_status
```

as A
and

```
P.post_type = 'post' AND P.post_status = 'private'
```

as B 
so it is

```
A or B
```

Comment: It is not expected result.